# Integrating DotNetOpenAuth and WCF WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, dotnetopenauth, wcf-web-api

I am trying to create a RESTful web service based on [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP). I also need to control access using OAuth and for this I am using the DotNetOpenAuth open source library.

Has anyone ever been successful integrating the two? I am struggling converting from the HTTP entities representations of the WCF Web API into something that's understandable by DNOA (e.g. HTTP requests, HTTP headers, etc...).

Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest cross-posting your question at the [WCF WebAPI discussion page](http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/4885/web-api).  Some pretty smart and in-the-know people are floating around there.  Being such a young (and alpha) library, may get extra visibility there to this great question.

Comment: Done: http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/267859

Comment: I suggest you bug this guy https://twitter.com/#!/GQAdonis2008  He was working on an OAuth implementation for WCF Web API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be a little more specific?

In WebAPI a request is represented by the [`HttpRequestMessage`](http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/417c9a96fc24#WCFWebApi/Http/Src/Microsoft.Net.Http/HttpRequestMessage.cs) class. A response is represented by the [`HttpResponseMessage`](http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/417c9a96fc24#WCFWebApi/Http/Src/Microsoft.Net.Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs) class.

I've no previous knowledge of DNOA, but from what I saw, you can easily create a `HttpRequestInfo` from an `HttpRequestMessage` using the public `HttpRequestInfo(string httpMethod, Uri requestUrl, string rawUrl, WebHeaderCollection headers, Stream inputStream)`.

The HTTP method and request uri are directly `HttpRequestMessage` properties.
The input stream is obtained via the `Content` property.  I don't see a direct way of creating a `WebHeaderCollection` from the WebAPI's `HttpRequestHeaders`. However, you can iterate the `HttpRequestHeaders` entries and insert then on the `WebHeaderCollection` one by one.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing after some more research. Good that you confirmed it. Marking your answer as correct for future readers.

Comment: how did you create de Stream object from the Content property of the HttpRequestMessage? @PedroFelix